# How to pop drop down list upon clicking a button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am a beginner in angularjs, i want to know what code should be used if i want to pop up a drop down depending upon the button being clicked.
If i click on India, the drop down corresponding to India should appear and if I click on Pakistan, the drop down corresponding to Pakistan should appear.

This is what I've tried so far :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>

  button 
   { background-color: #4CAF50;
     color: white;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 16px ; 
   }

</style>

<body>


<div>
<br/>

<button type = "India" ng-click= "India_dropDown">India </button> <br/> <br/>
<button type = "Pakistan" ng-click= "Pakistan_dropDown">Pakistan </button>
</div>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model= "India_dropDown" ng-options= " x for x in names1">
</select>
<select ng-model= "Pakistan_dropDown" ng-options= " y for y in names2">
</select>
</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp' , [] );
app.controller('myCtrl' , function($scope) {
  $scope.names1 = ['Sachin' ,'Dhoni','Virat','Dravid'] ;
  $scope.names2 = ['Shoaib' ,'Malik','Irfan','Sarfraz'] ;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by `Popping up`. Do you mean to open the dropdown so it displays it's options or to perform some animation?

Comment: I just want to have the drop down appear upon clicking on the button.

Comment: No animation is to be done.

Comment: you are porbbaly looking for `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, or `ng-if`

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically show or hide each select box using `ng-show`.

```
<div ng-show="country === 'Packistan'">
    <!-- pakistan select -->
</div>

<div ng-show="country === 'India'">
    <!-- India select -->
</div>
```

Toggle country by what was clicked.

```
<button id="India" ng-click="toggleCountry($event)">India</button>
<button id="Pakistan" ng-click="toggleCountry($event)">Pakistan</button>
```

In your controller...

```
$scope.country = "";
$scope.toggleCountry = function(e) {
    $scope.country = e.target.id;
}
```

Or just set it directly in the `ng-click` action.

```
<button id="India" ng-click="country = 'India';">India</button>
<button id="Pakistan" ng-click="country = 'Pakistan';">Pakistan</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/o40xhrch/) to demo the solution. Basically I am triggering the mouse down event on the required select box which will pop the box.

**Controller**

```
$scope.indiaDropDown = function() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('indiaselect');
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

$scope.pakDropDown = function() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('pakselect');
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <select ng-model="India_dropDown" id="indiaselect" ng-options=" x for x in names1">
  </select>
  <select ng-model="Pakistan_dropDown" id="pakselect" ng-options=" y for y in names2"></select>
  <br/>
  <button type="India" ng-click="indiaDropDown()">India </button>
  <br/>
  <button type="Pakistan" ng-click="pakDropDown()">Pakistan </button>
```

I am not sure if you pop open the dropdowns or just show/hide it. Incase you want to just show/hide the select boxes consider using ng-show/ng-hide. My solution will pop open the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">


            <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div>
                <button type="button" ng-click="setCountry(india)">India</button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="setCountry(pakistan)">Pakistan </button>
            </div>
            <select ng-model="country_select" ng-options="x for x in country"></select>
            </div>


            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp' , [] );
                
                app.controller('myCtrl' , ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    $scope.country = [];
                    $scope.india = ['Sachin' ,'Dhoni','Virat','Dravid'];
                    $scope.pakistan = ['Shoaib' ,'Malik','Irfan','Sarfraz'];
                    
                    $scope.setCountry = function(name){
                        $scope.country = name;
                    };
                }]);
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```